# Leaving & alone in regex

Tags: regex, c#-3.0, regex-negation

I am using C# Regex.

How can I match (Any lower upper and/or &)

```
A & E    ==> Should leave this as is
a & e    ==> Should leave this as is
```

and not this

```
A &#1234 B ==> Should convert to A B

A&#1234 B ==> Should convert to A B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you really just want to remove &#Digit from the string?

```
new Regex(" ?&#[0-9]+").Replace("A&#1234", "")
```